# Retrofit2: Modifying request body (Json) in OkHttp

Tags: java, android

I want to make a request in Android modifying the BODY with a JSON but at the same time modifying the HEADER, thus being able to obtain a response service.
Now I only have the code to modify the header but now I have to do the same (modify the header) and send a Json to the body to get another Json answer

```
public String abc="Basic "+Login.enco;
public Service getClientService() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", abc)
                        .build();


                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(Service.class);
    }
enter code here
    try {
        final List<String> lista = new ArrayList();

        RestApiAdapter restApiAdapter = new RestApiAdapter();
        Service service = restApiAdapter.getClientService();
        Call<JsonObject> call = service.getDataUser();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                JsonObject userJson = response.body().getAsJsonObject("LogOnResult");
                Log.d("response2", userJson.get("Usuario").getAsString());
                Log.d("response3", userJson.get("Token").getAsString());
                Log.d("response4", userJson.get("TipoUser").getAsString());
                Log.d("response5", userJson.get("IdUsuario").getAsString());
                UserModel user = new UserModel(
                        userJson.get("Usuario").getAsString(),
                        userJson.get("Token").getAsString(),
                        userJson.get("TipoUser").getAsString(),
                        userJson.get("IdUsuario").getAsString()
                );

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No existe conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }catch (Throwable e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No existe conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Retrofit2 you can pass header, query, body params via method params. All you need just specify annotations. Below is an example.


**Java Example:**

```
@POST("adduser")
Call<User> addUser(@Header("Authorization") String header, @Body User userModel);
```

Check this [links](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html#authentication-with-annotations) for more examples.